# Can we host subdomains to diffrent hosting provider?

Tags: web-hosting, domains

I have one domain, abc.com and for some reson I want to Install one application which require tomcat service. Current hosting is for php and apache only.

Is it possible to host java.abc.com to another hosting and how it can be done?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's no problem. Just create a different DNS record for java.abc.com and set it to the IP address for the other hosting company.

Comment: By IP address you means name servers?

Comment: No, I mean the IP address for your hosting account. There's only one set of name servers involved, for the abc.com domain; you're just creating another A record for the java.abc.com subdomain.